# iPad: weird frames at load and after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, frame

I have dynamically sized labels and table view row heights. Something does not seem to work. I log the width of a label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
Loading in Portrait --> 595
Rotate to Landscape --> 851
Rotate to Portrait  --> 595
```

Looks OK. But

```
Loading in Landscape --> 595
Rotate to Portrait   --> 595
Rotate to Landscape  --> 851
```

And indeed, my view label and cell is not rendered correctly when loading the view in landscape mode.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

When I rotate, I simply call `reloadData` on the table view in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`. That works like a charm.

I am **not** changing the width of the label anywhere, just the height. (Of course, the width is important for calculating the height, but I am not changing the width.)

The log statement is at the *end* of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which is always called *after* `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, so there are no more changes after that.

**EDIT 2**:

The label in question is created dynamically. I now switched to using a different frame for each orientation:

```
// in cellForRowAtIndexPath
BOLL landscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
//...
textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, landscape ? 851 : 595, h);
```

The label is initialized with this frame.

Comment: where do you change the width of the textfield? what do you call/your code when ipad rotates?

Comment: See my edit. I am not changing the width.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks like you are not checking to see what happens when you load in landscape. More code would provide you a fix :-)

Comment: Where to check? What to check? I am checking the width of the autoresized text field. It is reported wrong. What else?

Answer (score 0):

The solution: set the frame again in

```
-(void)willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: "Again"? I'm just checking to see if you are over-writing your code. Why are you setting the frame size more than once? Also, did you sub-class your UITableViewCell?

Comment: OK, not again. It is initialized with a frame, but its height gets recalculated. Thus, "again". Thanks for watching out for me!